# manipulating 3D array in python

Tags: python, list

I'm getting the following error when I run the code given below. Still learning Python, so where am I going wrong in my understanding ?  What is the fix?

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 26, in 
cube[1:3, 1:3]= ['*', '*', '*']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

```
cube = [[[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],

        [[':)', 'x', 'x'],  
         [':(', 'x', 'x'], # --> want this element to be ['*', '*', '*']
         [':)', 'x', 'x'], # --> want this element to be ['*', '*', '*']
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],

        [[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'], # --> want this element to be ['*', '*', '*']
         [':)', 'x', 'x'], # --> want this element to be ['*', '*', '*']
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],
         
        [[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],
         
        [[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x']]]
         
cube[1:3, 1:3] = ['*', '*', '*']

print(cube)
```

Comment: You can't put commas in `[]` while trying to access a list. If you see people online doing it, that's not a normal list. That's likely a numpy array which is a totally different thing. Use for loops to iterate down one dimension at a time and replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using nested lists, which are not truly 3D arrays. I would suggest you use `numpy` to get arrays that actually support that kind of slice based access:

```
import numpy as np
cube = np.array([[[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],

        [[':)', 'x', 'x'],  
         [':(', 'x', 'x'], 
         [':)', 'x', 'x'], 
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],

        [[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'], 
         [':)', 'x', 'x'], 
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],
         
        [[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x']],
         
        [[':(', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':)', 'x', 'x'],
         [':(', 'x', 'x']]])
         
cube[1:3, 1:3] = ['*', '*', '*']

print(cube)
```

Output:

```
[[[':(' 'x' 'x']
  [':)' 'x' 'x']
  [':(' 'x' 'x']
  [':(' 'x' 'x']]

 [[':)' 'x' 'x']
  ['*' '*' '*']
  ['*' '*' '*']
  [':(' 'x' 'x']]

 [[':(' 'x' 'x']
  ['*' '*' '*']
  ['*' '*' '*']
  [':(' 'x' 'x']]

 [[':(' 'x' 'x']
  [':)' 'x' 'x']
  [':)' 'x' 'x']
  [':(' 'x' 'x']]

 [[':(' 'x' 'x']
  [':)' 'x' 'x']
  [':)' 'x' 'x']
  [':(' 'x' 'x']]]
```